# Как использовать Microsoft SQL Server в Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, веб-программирование

Мне бы просто использовать MsSQL в Laravel 5.2 вместо MySQL. При этом было бы классно, если не пришлось бы переписывать какие-то участки кода, адаптировать лару.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В config/database.php заменить 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'), на 'default' => 'sqlsrv', в 'connections' => [ дописать
`'sqlsrv' => [
  'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
  'host' => 'host',
  'database' => 'database',
  'username' => 'user',
  'password' => 'pass',
  'prefix' => 'prefix_',
],`

Answer (score 1):

Как дополнение:

Если ПХП запущен на Linux то надо использовать `dblib` драйвер.

Для Mac OS нужно еще установить/сконфигурировать FreeTDS.

```
/etc/freetds/freetds.conf
[global]
        # TDS protocol version
;       tds version = 4.2

        # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
        # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
;       dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
;       debug flags = 0xffff

        # Command and connection timeouts
;       timeout = 10
;       connect timeout = 10

        # If you get out-of-memory errors, it may mean that your client
        # is trying to allocate a huge buffer for a TEXT field.  
        # Try setting 'text size' to a more reasonable limit 
        text size = 64512

# Define a connection to the MSSQL server.
[xyz]
        host = xyz
        port = 1433
        tds version = 8.0
```