# OsTicket нужно подключить к MS SQL SERVER

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, mysqli, mysqlconnector

Привет всем,

У меня OsTicket 1.19.12 и нужно подключиться к MS SQL Server 2008. Есть ли у кого то опыт работы с OsTicket? Там все написано для подключения к MySQL,а мне нужно строго к MS SQL Server, так как свои серверы и все подключено через MS SQL Server

Заранее благодарю за помощь

Comment: Если они используют PDO, ORM  или какой-то уровень абстракции,  то вам повезло и просто поменяйте драйвер соиденения

Если нет то ни как :).

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/537224/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-microsoft-sql-server-%D0%B2-laravel-5-2/537322#537322

Comment: PDO есть но файл очень сложно написан, с функциями, классами, которые вызываются с 10-ки файлов... Думал, может есть какое то решение

Comment: Ищем `new PDO(...);`  Первый пораметр это строка соединения. В этой строке до `:` драйвер. Меняем на `sqlsrv` или `dblib` в зависимости от системы смотрите ссылку что я вам уже дал. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php